# ''Fazer em casa dele'' ou "Fazer na casa dele"

Tags: gramática, diferenças-transatlânticas

Estava conversando com um português, amigo meu, e em certo momento ele disse

> ''Farei a lavanderia em casa de meu amigo.''

Após ouvir isso eu disse ''Nossa, no Brasil nós falariamos  *na casa de um amigo* ao invés de *em casa de um amigo*.'' conversamos um pouco sobre o que seria o correto e não chegamos a nenhuma conclusão.

Minha pergunta é a seguinte: Do ponto de vista gramatical (PT-BR e PT-EU) ambas as frases são coretas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As duas formas são perfeitamente gramaticais.  Em pt-BR é mais comum usarmos o artigo definido + a preposição quando nos referimos à casa de alguém.  Quando nos referimos à nossa própria casa, não usamos o artigo.

- Estou **na** casa de um amigo. ("na" = "em" + "a")
- Estou **em** casa. (a minha casa)
- Voltava **à** casa de Álvaro quando encontrei a Manuela. (voltava para a casa)
- Já era tarde e voltava **a** casa quando encontrei a Manuela. (voltava para casa)

Comment: talvez voce consiga me responder mais uma pergunta, uma vez que é um rapaz esperto. Estava conversando com esse meu amigo portugues, em certo momento eu disse *Foi o Vasco da Gama o primeiro português a chegar as Indias*, ele me disse que tal construção não é correta pois existe um distanciamento entre eu e Vasco da Gama portanto eu deveria falar *Foi Vasco da Gama o primeiro português a chegar as Indias*. Você sabe me dizer se o que eu disse está incorreto? (eu particurlamente acho que está, mas queria uma confimação)

Comment: @MatheusManzatto Você talvez queira checar: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1105/2764 e https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/7787/2764.