# Diferença entre "o fulano disse que..." e "fulano disse que..." (citação)

Tags: português-brasileiro, frases, artigos-definidos

Existe alguma diferença entre **"O João / A Maria disse que..."** e **"C.S.Lewis   / Jesus / (algum escritor) disse que..."**?

Se por exemplo eu pegar a segunda frase e adicionar o artigo (creio que seja o nome correto) na frente do sujeito, assim como na primeira frase, soaria estranho.

**Exemplo: "O Jesus / O Ziraldo disse que..."**

Creio que isso possa estar relacionado ao fato de se estar citando a fala de alguém famoso, algum escritor, etc, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: *Ziraldo disse...* = Algum Ziraldo disse (qual Ziraldo?); *O Ziraldo disse...* = Um Ziraldo específico (deduzo que o locutor e o ouvindo sabem quem é esse Ziraldo).

Comment: Grégor, já há uma [pergunta sobre isto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/366/is-there-a-general-rule-for-using-articles-before-proper-nouns) e ainda [esta outra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/is-it-mandatory-to-use-the-definite-article-before-a-given-name/1108#1108); estão é em inglês.

Comment: @Jacinto obrigado! Realmente não havia passado pela minha cabeça que poderiam existir perguntas em inglês também.

Comment: Nem eu me lembrava que estavam em inglês. Sabia que existiam perguntas sobre o tópico, mas tive dificuldade em encontrá-las porque estava a procurar palavras-chave em português.

Comment: Grégor, a minha impressão é que as respostas à tua pergunta, no seu melhor, simplesmente repetem coisas que já estão nas respostas a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/is-it-mandatory-to-use-the-definite-article-before-a-given-name). Então eu sugiro que faças uma de duas coisas. Fechar a tua pergunta como duplicata (clica em "close" e seleciona "duplicate"). Ou então edita a tua pergunta, explicando o que é que ainda queres saber para além do que já está respondido na outra pergunta antiga. Podes simplesmente dizer, "nas respostas à outra pergunta >>

Comment: >> [inclui link] já se diz isto, mas eu fiquei ainda com esta dúvida [explica dúvida]. Caso contrário receio que obtenhas aqui simplesmente repetições do que já lá está. Se preferires fechar com duplicata e tiveres dificuldades, diz-me, que eu inicio o processo, e depois já é mais fácil para ti.

Comment: @Jacinto, coloquei como duplicata mesmo. Não estou muito acostumado a acompanhar as notificações do stackexchange, pois tenho minha conta em apenas um dispositivo, então peço desculpas pela demora.

Answer (score 3):

Besides regional variety described by Zuabros, there is a formality nuance about the the presence/absence of the article.

When using the article a subtle informality is present, most likely meaning the speaker is acquainted with the person he or she is talking about.

When formality is needed (in an article, news, narrative literature, report etc), usually we omit the article.

P.S: I'm from Southeast of Brazil. In North and Northeast I think the article is hardly ever used, even in informal conversation).

Comment: I don't think there's a formality difference and I've got my doubts about regional difference. I don't disagree with you because I don't know if I am right or wrong. I always thought about it in the same way that said in my answer, but, as I said, I don't actually.

Comment: I don't know where you are from, but where I live, southeast Brazil, the two cases are definitely true: We always use the article before a person's name, except when formality is needed.

Comment: [Here](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1105/is-it-mandatory-to-use-the-definite-article-before-a-given-name?noredirect=1&lq=1) you can see answers very similar to mine.

Comment: Interesting. Where I live, both ways are formal.

Comment: I am from São Paulo, São Bernardo do Campo.

Comment: @Schilive, eu posso confirmar que em Portugal é como o Charley diz. É claro, há sempre umas complicações. Em conversa acerca de pessoas comuns, usa-se, em Portugal, normalmente o artigo, mesmo se a conversa for formal. Por exemplo, se eu estivesse a testemunhar num tribunal, eu diria,"**O** João da Silva só chegou ao local depois...". Mas se eu disser, "Já **o** Camões dizia...", é decididamente informal; com um mínimo de formalidade, trabalho escolar, por exemplo, seria, "Já Camões dizia..."

Comment: Agora, Charley, a pergunta está em português, a tua resposta devia também ser em português.

Comment: Jacinto, eu preferi escrever em inglês porque penso que pessoas que estão ainda aprendendo a língua portuguesa podem entender melhor uma explicação em inglês do que em português.

Comment: @Jacinto, engraçado. Essa formalidade é oficial ou varia com o autor? Digo, se eu disser "o Camões é bonito", é informal porque está na gramática ou é informal, dependendo do autor? Para mim, nunca houve diferença de formalidade.

Comment: Charley, a conclusão a que se chegou [nesta discussão no meta](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/should-i-answer-questions-in-portuguese-or-english) (que é onde se discutem as regras de funcionamento do site) é que se se deve responder na língua da pergunta ou nas duas línguas (que nunca prejudica). (Quando te diriges, aqui nos comentários, a alguém, convém incluir @ antes do nome, para a pessoa ser notificada; eu não preciso de o fazer para ti, porque este é um post teu, e por isso és notificado de tudo.)

Comment: @Schilive, oficial, só mesmo a ortografia. Tudo o resto são padrões de uso. No uso que eu sempre vi, depende do contexto, não da pessoa. Mesmo, acerca de um tipo que quase ninguém conhece, num artigo de jornal eu escreveria, "Paulo B. chegou à conclusão...", mas em conversa com amigos diria, "O Paulo B. é meu amigo de longa data." Aqui em Portugal, num jornal ou notícia na TV, é sempre "Paulo B.", "Jorge Jesus", sempre sem artigo. Em conversa com amigos juntamos quase sempre o artigo.

Answer (score 1):

A língua portuguesa, em ambas as variedades, português europeu e português brasileiro (PTBR), admite o uso facultativo de artigo diante de nomes de pessoas ou antropónimos. No Sudeste do Brasil, em geral, bem como em Portugal, usa-se; já no Nordeste do Brasil, não é comum.

Um morador dos estados do Sul e Sudeste (São Paulo, Rio de Janeiro, Paraná, Santa Catarina, Rio Grande do Sul) dirá:

> - Mãe!! A Mariazinha pegou meu brinquedo!

Já um morador do norte / nordeste do Brasil dirá:

> - Mãe!! Mariazinha pegou meu brinquedo!

Comment: tens alguma referência? Eu nunca pensei que poderia existir variedade regional disso.

Comment: Referencia: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/artigo-definido-com-nomes-proprios/21809#:~:text=O%20artigo%20pode%20ser%20usado,diante%20do%20nome%20da%20pessoa.

Comment: Importante é que essas observações são de carater prático, e acabam não sendo muito úteis para realização de provas de proficiência da lingua portuguesa, quando acabam perguntando sempre as exceções, que muitas vezes são bizarras mesmo para os falantes nativos. Um exemplo muito usado em provas de português é a palavra "palácio": Quando a palavra “palácio” estiver desacompanhada de algum modificador, o artigo não deverá ser utilizado. Ex: "Vou ao palácio" = errado. "Vou a palácio" = certo.Se você quer uma referência técnica: https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/gramatica/emprego-artigo-definido.htm

Comment: obrigado. Por sinal, essa regra de "palácio" eu nunca vou respeitar.

Comment: discordo tanto dessas regras no site. Não sei se têm sentido em Portugal, mas, aqui, não tem sentido nenhum. Nunca vou respeitá-las.

Comment: Não discordo de todas, mas de várias.

Comment: pelo que vi, "estou no palácio" está correto, mas, de acordo com Bechara, é costume falar "estou em palácio". Procede?

Comment: @Schilive e Zuabros, convém sempre ver vários sites. [Neste outro](https://www.portalsaofrancisco.com.br/portugues/artigo) diz apenas: "**Costuma-se** omitir o artigo com a palavra palácio **quando** designa a residência ou o local de despacho de um chefe de governo". Ainda assim, cheira-me que é apenas em frases como "Esteve em palácio, por convocação do senhor Governador", "O senador foi chamado a palácio", "O presidente ainda estava em palácio", mas que se dirá, falando da mesma coisa, *o palácio é bonito*. Compararem "ele está em casa" vs "a casa é bonita".

Comment: @Jacinto, vale lembrar que ninguém vai morrer ou sair correndo pelado na rua, porque alguém escreveu "estou no palácio".

Comment: Do ponto de vista da gramática forma, que será cobrada em provas: Se a palavra palácio tiver um qualificador, leva artigo: "Vou ao palácio alvorada". Vou ao palácio real."  ambas são a forma correta, porém diz-se: "O presidente terminou seus afazeres, portanto voltará a palácio." O rei sempre dorme em palácio."  Errado seria dizer que o rei dorme "no" palácio ou voltará "ao" palácio. 
Na linguagem informal, do dia-a-dia, usa sempre o artigo, porém já vi muitas quesetões de concursos e de vestibulares cobrando a forma correta, sem o artigo definido quando palácio não acompanha um qualificador.