# Na casa do meu amigo ou em casa do meu amigo?

Tags: gramática, artigos-definidos

Estava conversando com meu amigo e ele me mandou uma foto dizendo *estou em casa do meu amigo*, mas eu acho que o certo de dizer seria *na casa do meu amigo*.

Alguém pode me tirar essa dúvida: se está certo dizer *na casa* ao invés de *em casa*.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Is it mandatory to use the definite article before a given name?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1105/2764), [Diferença entre "o fulano disse que..." e "fulano disse que..." (citação) {duplicate}](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/7787/2764).

Answer (score 1):

Ambos estão corretos, embora a expressão com artigo (i.e., "na casa") seja mais comum, e "em casa" seja mais usado em oposição a "fora (de casa)". No Ciberdúvidas, a expressão sem artigo ("em casa") é qualificada como [literária](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/naem-casa/19176) e [formal](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/estou-naem-casa-do-pedro/23522).